# identify specific numeral from message having multiple numerals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to pick 3rd numeric values from a message. This numeral could be of 1 length, 2 length, 4 length etc. I am using PATINDEX to get the index of numeral but not sure how to get it to look for 3rd numeral directly.

**Message :**

```
'Successfully imported 6609 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6609 records into the table'
```

**Query :**

```
select (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'Successfully imported 6609 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6609 records into the table')
```

**Modified Query:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING
('Successfully imported 6609 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6609 records into the table .%' ,
PATINDEX('%total of%' ,'Successfully imported 6609 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6609 records into the table .%') + 9, 
5)
```

I am getting the output as 6609 which is specific to this message only , but if my message is  'Successfully imported 6 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6 records into the table .' , then i am not getting expected output .

**Expected output :**

```
6609 -- 3rd numeral
```

Comment: Will your string always be in the format above? If so, why not just get the value after `'total of'`?

Comment: I have updated my post , please suggest.

Comment: Is your 3rd number is the last number in your string?

Comment: *"I have updated my post , please suggest."* I'm going to read that comment as a "Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 3rd number is the last number in your string (always), you can use this below logic to get the 3rd number-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad8db307231ffd11921bc7cc93effe2e)

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(1000)
SET @T = 'Successfully imported 6609 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6609 records into the table'


SELECT 
REVERSE
(
    SUBSTRING
    (
        REVERSE(@T),
        PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@T)),
        (CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@T),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@T))))-(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@T)))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the besst solution but it works :

```
WITH source(message) AS
  (SELECT 'Successfully imported 1 records and updated 2 records for a total of 3 records into the table')
SELECT value
FROM SOURCE CROSS apply
  (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY message) POSITION, value
   FROM string_split(message, ' ')
   WHERE try_cast(value AS int) IS NOT NULL) AS a
WHERE POSITION = 3
```

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT()` does not guarantee the order of the substrings, as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Answer (score 0):

Databases in general is not the right place for string manipulation, this kind of work should be in the front end.
However, you could use the following

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES T.String, SS.Value
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('Successfully imported 6609 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6609 records into the table'),
  ('Successfully imported 6609 records and updated 0 records for a total of 9999 records into the table')
) T(String)
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TRY_CAST(Value AS INT)) RN,
         Value
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(String, ' ')
) SS
ORDER BY RN DESC;
```

<kbd>[`Online Demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a2c0f3b7efb5c5d1d868228b8ae367e)</kbd>

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string." It was added in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below query , and its working as expected.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING
('Successfully imported 0 records and updated 0 records for a total of 0 records into the table .%' ,
PATINDEX('%total of%' ,'Successfully imported 0 records and updated 0 records for a total of 0 records into the table .%') + 9, 
PATINDEX('%records into the table%' ,'Successfully imported 0 records and updated 0 records for a total of 0 records into the table .%') -
(PATINDEX('%total of%' ,'Successfully imported 0 records and updated 0 records for a total of 0 records into the table .%') + 9) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic on your **2** examples, you want the value after `total of`, so just find that, and then the first space after:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.YourString,PI.I+DATALENGTH('total of '),CHARINDEX(' ',V.YourString,PI.I+DATALENGTH('total of ')) - (PI.I+DATALENGTH('total of '))))
FROM (VALUES('Successfully imported 6609 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6609 records into the table'),
            ('Successfully imported 6 records and updated 0 records for a total of 6 records into the table .'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%total of%',V.YourString)))PI(I)
```